# Moving a RAID5 from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid, mdadm

I've converted a Windows 10 box over to Ubuntu 18.04 . I've been using a Mobius 5-Bay external enclosure set to RAID5 for a few years and am now attempting to mount and use it in Ubuntu. After looking for solutions to the problem, I'm still not having any luck.

If I run `lsblk` or `lsscsi` I can see the individual disks listed but that's about it.

```
$ lsscsi
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      OCZ-VERTEX2 3.5  1.27  /dev/sda 
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD20EARS-00M AB51  /dev/sdb 
[5:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH20NS15  IL00  /dev/sr0 
[6:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Mobius  DISK1    0962  /dev/sdc 
[6:1:0:0]    disk    ATA      Mobius  DISK2    0962  /dev/sdd 
[6:2:0:0]    disk    ATA      Mobius  DISK3    0962  /dev/sde 
[6:3:0:0]    disk    ATA      Mobius  DISK4    0962  /dev/sdf 
[6:4:0:0]    disk    ATA      Mobius  DISK5    0962  /dev/sdg`enter code here`
```

and

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   4.9M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/50
loop1    7:1    0   624K  1 loop /snap/nano-editor/1
loop2    7:2    0  87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5742
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 111.3G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0   1.8T  0 part 
sdc      8:32   1   3.7T  0 disk 
sdd      8:48   1   3.7T  0 disk 
sde      8:64   1   3.7T  0 disk 
sdf      8:80   1   3.7T  0 disk 
sdg      8:96   1   2.7T  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

No results from an assemble scan.

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

There are no filesystems so a specific `--examine` on any of the `/dev/***` does not work either.

Without a raid partition listed, things get a bit muddy for me and I'm not sure what to do next. I don't want to risk any loss, but the data *is* backed up. If I plug it into my other Win10 machine, it works fine. If needed, I am open to a rebuild but trying to avoid it. This seems like it can be done.

**Background** - I am pretty inexperienced.  This is my only raid setup and it's just worked. I set it up once with no issues. I have limited experience with linux and this is my first personal setup. I'm currently earning an IT related degree and have a linux course on the horizon. I made the switch to educate myself but believe I'll continue to utilize linux on this machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.